Azure CD failed to make AndroidSigning

Exception in thread "main" com.android.apksig.apk.MinSdkVersionException: Failed to determine APK's minimum supported platform version. Use --min-sdk-version to override

I have add this task to sign
- task: AndroidSigning@3
        inputs:
          apkFiles: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.aab'  
          apksignerKeystoreFile: 'mykeystore'  
          apksignerKeystorePassword: '*****'  
          apksignerKeystoreAlias: '*****'
          apksignerKeyPassword: '*****' 


Since --min-sdk-version is an apksigner command argument, you just need to add the apksignerArguments input with the value -min-sdk-version <INTEGER> to override it with the value of your choice.
I've encountered this issue this morning using .NET MAUI. My guess is that if you don't have anything defined in your AndroidManifest.xml using android:minSdkVersion="<INTEGER>", the AndroidSigning@3 task is not able to resolve this by itself. I didn't try to set this up in my manifest using this theory since MAUI manage it on its Heads project, but you might want to try it if you want to avoid managing both your project and your pipeline for the minimum android sdk version.
AndroidSigning@3 doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/android-signing-v3?view=azure-pipelines
Android apksigner doc: https://developer.android.com/tools/apksigner
